# using elixir mix.version() in Laravel causes view to fail

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-5.3, laravel-elixir

I'm a new in Laravel and am trying to use the mix.version() in the Gulpfile.js in Laravel 5.3 for cache busting.

this is my gulpfile.js:

```
    elixir(function (mix){
    mix.less('custom.less');
    mix.version('public/css/custom.css');
    });
```

When running gulp command in my terminal, my less is compiled and versioned correctly, but when I try to include the the following line my view file, it breaks my view:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('/css/custom.css) }}">
```

[screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72z6H.png)

Is there a specific include or something I need to call in my view file to ensure the above line of code actually works? If I remove the above elixir line in my view code and hard code link my css file, then it works, but I can't leave it like that as I need versioning for cache busting.

Thanks so much, I have tried the documentation, but not examples exist of how to include the code in the view file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ' missing

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('/css/custom.css) }}">
```

should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ elixir('/css/custom.css') }}">
```

Regarding the question title

```
{{ elixir('/css/custom.css) }}
```

is causing the error not the mix.version()

Comment: Frank, I am feeling quite embarrassed right now. Thanks so much